# Reversibility of Physical Process : QM vs CM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, reversibility, time-reversal-symmetry

It is often stated that the processes in quantum mechanics are reversible as they follow the Schrodinger's Equation  : $$ - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \Psi(x,t) + V(x,t)\ \Psi(x,t) = i \hbar\ \frac{\partial \Psi(x,t)}{\partial t}  $$ which is valid for $t$ as well as $-t$.

I have a few doubts about the reversibility :

1. Since classical mechanics is just an approximation of quantum mechanics how do we describe the apparently irreversible processes (like turning of wood into coal or turning of sunlight into food by plants) as reversible? I think one could say that some information is lost, classically, and hence those processes can't be reversed. If only we had that information we could, in principle, reverse them. This gives rise to two possibilities of the meaning of reversible :

   a) If the clock were run backwards (or a movie of the process run backwards) the process would look the same.

   b) If we had all the information then (barring technological hindrances) we can reverse the process.

   Which one of the above is correct?
2. Even quantum mechanically it is possible to have physical quantities like transmission probability which are independent of time. How do we demonstrate the reversibility in such cases? For example let's say we have a particle in an *finite* potential well (standard textbook case) and it has some transition probability. An observation found the particle outside the well. How can we demonstrate the reversibility if the transition probability is itself time independent?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were just talking about t-symmetry, not CPT which we think always holds together. Going to say a few general statements first.

T-symmetry breaks down for the following reasons.

> 1. intrinsic to the dynamic physical law (e.g., for the weak force)
> 2. due to the initial conditions of our universe (e.g., for the second law of thermodynamics)
> 3. due to measurements (e.g., for the noninvasive measurements)
>    [1] https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry

Ignore 1&3 for a minute, 2 is by far the most important here.

Note:

> delicate experiments in which known sources of dissipation are removed reveal that the laws of [classical] mechanics are time reversal invariant. Dissipation itself is originated in the second law of thermodynamics.[1]

This says the classical laws themselves are time reversal invariant. Any t can be replaced by -t for a completely valid solution. So why do we observe so few -t processes, like a ball rolling back up a hill? Because of 2. There is extra stuff beyond the classical laws themselves, namely the initial/prior conditions of the universe. Due to an extremely low entropy big bang, certain solutions are preferenced. Systems dissapate and there is a macroscopic second law. Even though all the -t solutions are possible, the initial condition of the universe (dense, extremely low entropy) together with the second law only create a subset. This is 99.9% of why we see a macroscopic arrow of time.

1&3 are both quantum effects, if 3 even exists. 1 says there *are* in-built t-assymetries in some of the quantum dynamical laws, namely in the weak and strong force. There is always CPT symmetry though. But these effects in the laws themselves are not why we have a macroscopic second law. And 3 is even less important.

So you have mostly t-symmetric or perfectly t-symmetric laws in classical mechanics, but not every solution is observed due to how the universe is evolving since its prior conditions. As far as a) vs b), the latter is basically correct. The former is too but only for microscopic systems where the second law doesn't come into play. Otherwise there *is* a preferred direction, namely the second law, when systems become large enough.

Comment: So one major point of your argument is about _dissipative effects_. This is taken care of by the part where I said that if we have _enough_ knowledge (basically the lost part / the dissipated part) then we could, in principle, reverse all the dissipative processes. As for the weak interaction, I honestly have no idea if such a thing is even applicable there. But I am not particularly concerned about the weak interaction here because the main motivation to ask this question to explore the Black Hole Information Paradox and its resolution.

Comment: There are various proposed solution to the paradox and one of them advocates that the information is not really lost. They _always_ use the fact that the transition from (eternal) black hole to radiation is unitary as this is a quantum process. I wanted to explore that idea.